# Is it possible to get the "download" link for a file request to a server (I guess it's a server) in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have this Fund family called Fidelity which I have to update monthly. It has ~250 funds on it's page.

E.g.: https://fundresearch.fidelity.com/mutual-funds/summary/316345206

On each I have to click on Prospectus & Reports, it will pop up a window, but my download will only start if I click on the Monthly Report button:

When I check the link for this single download it gives me this: https://www.actionsxchangerepository.fidelity.com/ShowDocument/ComplianceEnvelope.htm?_fax=-18%2342%23-61%23-110%23114%2378%23117%2320%23-1%2396%2339%23-62%23-21%2386%23-100%2337%2316%2335%23-68%2391%23-66%2354%23103%23-16%2369%23-30%2358%23-20%2376%23-84%23-11%23-87%230%23-50%23-20%23-92%23-98%23-116%23-28%2358%23-38%23-43%23-39%23-42%23-96%23-88%2388%23-45%23-88%2316%239%239%23104%23-128%23-21%23-39%23-74%235%23-89%23-105%23-67%23126%2377%23-126%23100%2345%23-44%23-73%23-15%238%23-21%23-37%23-17%23-14%23-98%23123%23-18%2345%23-59%23-82%2367%2383%23112%2317%2370%23-78%2378%23-50%2336%23-86%23-90%2381%23-21%23-119%23-30%23120%2349%2328%23-98%2333%2351%23-78%23-119%23-16%2350%23-58%2350%23102%2348%23-17%2352%23-99%23#

This changes monthly and this will only get me to this report, not to the latest one available.

But with these links I can't really recognise the changing part and it's logic.

My problem is that I am not really into javascript and can't really see the whole process that goes down on the site when I click on the button.

P.S.: The download comes w/o a file extension, but giving them all in Total Commander is the least of my worries. Let me know if you need any further details.

Is there any way I could save ~1500 clicks and a half day?

If there is any part which is not clear, let me know and I will elaborate.

Comment: You could, in theory, write a site scraping tool that would shortcut your process (and would, if written correctly, [not fall afoul of their Terms of Use](https://www.fidelity.com/terms-of-use#Means) so long as you artificially slow it down a little) - but you're far more likely to get help here if you start writing it and get stuck rather than just coming here with nothing but a dream and a smile.

Comment: I came here with a dream and a smile because I have no effing clue how to start writing one, hence the question.

Comment: [This may be helpful](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) to understand why StackOverflow is not a good fit for your question. If you don't know how to write the application you're looking for yourself, I recommend you seek out a freelancer who can do the job for you.